# Django and CKEditor as a template

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is it possible to use db variables in ckeditor? for example:

```
My name is : {{ form.name }}
My age is : {{ form.age }}
```

and then i can render the ckeditor entry as a template populated by the model.

All advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this is most certainly possible, but I don't quite understand what you are looking to do? Do you want to pre-fill the form fields with data from the database?

Comment: When I  write a document in RichTextField (ckeditor) i want to mail merge data from the db. Thanks for any help in advance